# How can i link other webpages using this xml?

Tags: html, css, xml, hyperlink

i have a subject for xml and our project is to create a xml webpages every data must be in xml and write it on a xml how can link other pages?
Here's my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Home</title>
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "index.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "nav">
        <div class = "navigation">
        <script>
                            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            xmlhttp.open("GET","nav.xml",false);
                            xmlhttp.send();
                            xmldoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;


                            var x = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("title");
                            var y = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("a");


                        document.write("<ul>")

                            for(i = 0;i<x.length;i++){
                        document.write("<li><a href = "+ i">")
                        document.write(xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("title")    [i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                        document.write("</li></a>");

                            }
                            alert(y.length);
                            document.write("</ul>");    


                </script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "content">
        <div class = "logo">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "footer">
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

also i couldn't display the inline list of the element
CSS

```
html, body{
    margin:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.container{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url("bg.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
}
.navigation{
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
}
.nav{
    position:relative;
    height:12%;
    width:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.nav>ul{
    list-style-type: none;

}
.nav>ul>li{
    display:inline;
    padding:10px;

}
.content{
    position:relative;

    height:78%;
    width:100%;
}
.footer{
    position:relative;

    height:10%;
    width:100%;
}
.logo{
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-image:url("logo.png");
    background-size:100%;

}
```

the xml file

```
    <?xml version = "1.0"?>
<root>
    <nav xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <title xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="index.html">Home</title>
        <title xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="collection.html">Collection</title>
        <title xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="gamelibrary.html">Game Library</title>
        <title xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="platform.html">Platforms</title>
    </nav>
    <href>
        <a>collection.html</a>
        <a>gamelibrary.html</a>
    </href>
</root>
```